# dynamic datePicker in material ui Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-datepicker

I have a problem, I can not make actual dates in the datepicker. I have an array of date strings in a state. I only need to put these dates in the datepicker so that only these dates are available for clicking, how can I do this please?

Array of dates:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvrnA.png)

An example of how I want to do:

[Example of Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj9KZ.png)

I have a default datePicker from MUI https://codesandbox.io/s/v0xqj0?file=/demo.js

[Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph6cL.png)

I tried to use google, tried through renderday, but so far it did not work.
The maximum that happened is, it's funny))

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YypP0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the props "shouldDisableDate" to disable certain dates and pass a function that will return true if the value is not in your array of dates.

You have an example in the documentation here: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/

I forked your codesandbox here is what you could do: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-yonath-kvk59t?file=/demo.js:917-921

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will come in handy for someone... 
the parameter in the DesktopDatePicker helped me -

```
shouldDisableDate={getData}
```

and in it

```
const getData = (data) => {
dates.map((value) => {
some action...
})

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.